# Validity of natural deduction rules for first-order logic

Tags: first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I would like to read a proof on the validity of natural deduction rules for first-order logic.

The papers I have found:

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/atp/handouts/ch2-natded.pdf

and

https://homepage.univie.ac.at/christian.damboeck/ps06/clemente_nat_ded.pdf

introduce natural deduction and rely on intuition to understand these rules.

Is there a good account with a *proof* of the validity of natural deduction rules for first-order logic?

As I understand it is not possible to prove *completeness* of these rules for first-order logic since Gödel's non-completeness theorem. Am I right here?

Comment: Which rules of decduction would you accept to be used in a proof of the validity of the rules of deduction?

Comment: "it is not possible to prove completeness of these rules for first-order logic" is **wrong**: we have [Gödel's completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem). [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) is a different topic.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : well, Hilbert proof system?

Comment: For the [soundness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness) of the rules, you can see : Neil Tennant, [Natural logic](https://www.amazon.it/Natural-Logic-Neil-Tennant/dp/0852245793) (1978), page 71.

Comment: You can see also Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA87) (2007), **Theorem 3.9.2 (Soundness of Natural Deduction for Propositional Logic)**, page 87.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA : thanks